# Python Date Utility Library

Tags: python, datetime

Is there a library in python that can produce date dimensions given a certain day?  I'd like to use this for data analysis.  Often I have a time series of dates, but for aggregation purposes I'd like to be able to quickly produce dates associated with that day - like first date of month, first day in week, and the like.

I think I could create my own, but if there is something out there already it'd be nice.

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have a look at [`dateutil`](http://labix.org/python-dateutil).

The [recurrence rules](http://labix.org/python-dateutil#head-470fa22b2db72000d7abe698a5783a46b0731b57) and [relative deltas](http://labix.org/python-dateutil#head-ba5ffd4df8111d1b83fc194b97ebecf837add454) are what you want.

For example, if you wanted to get last monday:

```
import dateutil.relativedelta as rd
import datetime

last_monday = datetime.date.today() + rd.relativedelta(weekday=rd.MO(-1))
```

Answer (score 2):

### `time` and `datetime` modules

For some of your purposes you can use [`time` module](http://docs.python.org/library/time.html) with [`strftime()`](http://docs.python.org/library/time.html#time.strftime) method or [`date` module](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html) with its [`strftime()`](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.strftime) method. It allows you to pull, among other data:

- number of the week of the year,
- number of the weekday (you can also use [`weekday()` method](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.weekday) for getting weekday number between `0` for Monday and `6` for Sunday),
- year,
- month,

Which will suffice to calculate first day of the month, first day of the week and some other data.

### Examples

To pull the data you need, do just:

- to pull the number of the day of the week

  ```
  >>> from datetime import datetime
  >>> datetime.now().weekday()
  6
  ```
- to pull the first day of the month use `replace()` function of `datetime` object:

  ```
  >>> from datetime import datetime
  >>> datetime.now()
  datetime.datetime(2012, 3, 3, 21, 41, 20, 953000)
  >>> first_day_of_the_month = datetime.now().replace(day=1)
  >>> first_day_of_the_month
  datetime.datetime(2012, 3, 1, 21, 41, 20, 953000)
  ```

**EDIT**: As J.F. Sebastian suggested within comments, `datetime` objects have `weekday()` methods, which makes using `int(given_date.strftime('%w'))` rather pointless. I have updated the answer above.

Comment: `datetime` object has `weekday()` method, you don't need `strftime()` for that.